# How to get value from radio group?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am having following radio group in the template:

```
<v-radio-group
    v-model="selectedCheckFee"
    class="mx-n4"
    dense
    label="How would you like your check delivered?"
    mandatory
>
   <v-radio
      v-for="{value, label, type} in checkFeeOptions"
      :key="value"
      :value="value"
      :label="label"
      :data-testid="`checkFee${value}`"
   />
</v-radio-group>
```

Following is the vuejs code:

```
const checkFeeOptions = [
  {label: 'Regular mail ($5.00 fee)', value: 5, type: 'regular'},
  {label: 'Overnight mail ($30.00 fee)', value: 30, type: 'overnight'},
];

 data: () => ({
    selectedCheckFee: 0,
  }),
```

I want the type along with value of the selected radio button. How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `v-model` property of `<v-radio-group>` contains the value of the selected `<v-radio>`. To make it easier to find the one you selected, I would suggest add an id to each option and use it as the value.

To get the type of the selected option, you can then add a computed property like so:

```js
  computed: {
    selectedOptionType() {
      if (!this.selectedOptionId) {
        return "";
      }
      return this.options.find(o => o.id === this.selectedOptionId).type;
    }
  }
```

See this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chamboug/pen/xxVboVy?editors=1010) for a working example.